# onActivityResult return resultCode = -1

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have this code that allows me to select file from the SDcard and upload it to server, it was working fine in an activity. Now i switched to fragment and used the same code but it's not working. What is happening is that the onActivityResult() is called and the window to select file pop-up and when I select a file, nothing happens resultCode = -1. I don't know how to fix this.

Here is the code from the onActivityResult():

```
public void selectFile() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("Here ","onActivityResult");
    Log.i("Here ","onActivityResult");
    Log.i("resultCode ",resultCode+"");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("Here ","onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
            Log.i("Here ","onActivityResult");
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            String uriString = selectedFileUri.toString();
            Log.i("UriString ", uriString);
            File fileToUpload = new File(uriString);


            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedFileUri, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        uploadFileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    }
                    uploadFilePath = getPath(selectedFileUri);
                    Log.i("Upload File Path ", uploadFilePath);
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                uploadFileName = fileToUpload.getName();
                uploadFilePath = uriString.replace("file://", "");
                Log.i("Upload File Path ", uploadFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}




private String getPath(Uri selectedFileUri) {
    if (selectedFileUri == null)
        return null;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedFileUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return selectedFileUri.getPath();
}
```

Comment: -1 is `RESULT_OK`. You have several log statements, tell us what you are seeing. Better yet, step through with the debugger and narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: You mean the default value for RESULT_OK is -1 ?

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my life, I didn't know that RESULT_OK already exist in Activity, my mistake is i was creating an int RESULT_OK and its value is 0.

Comment: I know its a bit old, but I hope this will still reduce somebodies pain. I fixed a bad misbehaviour. My first Activity's onActivityResult() wasn’t returning RESULT_OK (value -1) after the second activity called finishWithResult(RESULT_OK, null). I gave it a try and removed the launchMode (mine was singleTask) of the second activity in AndroidManifest and after that it worked for me.